# Good place for starters to develop ArcGIS map

Tags: java, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-runtime

I am new to ArcGIS 10.2. I want to develop a Java application which displays map. Please guide me, where to start looking

Comment: I am guessing the downvotes you are receiving are a result of this question being perceived as not showing research effort. What if any research did you do before asking? The link in @Maksim's answer below is the second result of a simple "arcgis java" Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=arcgis+java

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.arcgis.com/java/

On the top of the page there are "Guide" and "API Reference" tabs, check those out.

Good luck!